# IBM Worklight V6.1 jquery mobile v1.4.3 change dynamic content, wait for DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to change dynamically the content of a div. 
My html page looks somehow like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
<body>
   <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
         //Image
      </div>

      <!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->
      <div id="pagePort"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in wlCommonInit() I call this:

```
$("#pagePort").load("page2.html", function(){
});
```

and nothing happen but if I include a timeout it works fine. So my intuition is that I have to wait for the div to be ready?
But on which event can I wait to call the .load() statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your claim.

I have tested the following in both Worklight 6.1.0.01-20140821-0406 (this is actually 6.1.0.2) and 6.2.0.00-20140918-1910  , and in both page2.html  loaded right away as the application was displayed while previewing it via Worklight Console:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <div data-role="page" id="page">
                <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                    <div data-role="header">
                    Header
                    </div>
                    <div id="pagePort"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

**main.js:**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    $("#pagePort").load("page2.html");
}
```

page2.html resides on the same level as index.html and contains only `<h1>Success</h1>`